# Doctrine - Configure Entities in more than one directory

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

I'm starting in Doctrine 2.4 and I'm developing a system where I separate the core files and application files, as follows:

```
 
/ root 
    |-- /Src 
         |-- / App 
               |-- /Model 
                     |- ** (Application Entities) ** 
         |-- /Core 
               |-- /Model 
                     |-- ** (Core Entities) **
```

In the Doctrine documentation shows the following form to set 1 directory for Esntitys:

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__. "/src"), $isDevMode);
```

But when I have to configure more than one directory that will contain the Entitys of my application, how to proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to resolve the issue. Simple!!!

Put like this:

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src/App/Model/", __DIR__."/src/Core/Model/"), $isDevMode);
```